# Connect android-x86 run on VirtualBox as USB device for debug

Tags: usb, virtualbox, android-x86

I have: Debian GNU/Linux 8.4 (jessie) installed on old Gygabyte laptop.

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T5250  @ 1.50GHz
```

I have VirtualBox: Version 5.0.20 r106931
On it I installed android-x86-2.3-RC1-eeepc.iso image.
Now I want debug my web sites.
So, how can I to connect guest as USB device?
All manuals just say how to use connected usb devices inside the guest.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the Android Virtual Devices that are part of the Android SDK. It'll probably be a better experience.

https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads

You'll have to scroll down on that page for the SDK only download, Google REALLY wants you to download Android Studio. ;)

Comment: Yes! Actually I installed and run it, but! I have no vt-x support and my computer is little bit old. So it runs EXTREMELY slow...